# How names files by their hash value?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to know how to name uploaded file by their hash value using 'upload_to' in models.ImageField or models.FileField.

I'm aware of [this](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-hashedfilenamestorage/) package, but I want to have more control over naming procedure.

My main problem is that instance is not really instance of model, because it haven't been saved yet. I've seen the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) but it didn't mention the workaround or at least I didn't get it.

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    pass
```

Comment: From what to you want to compose the hash. The file content?

Comment: Yes, from file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `instance` field that contains an instance of `UploadFile` and you can read the contents:

```
import hashlib

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return hashlib.sha1(instance.field.read()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'field'. Image is my model object.

Comment: You replace field with your field name. I don't know the name of the field.